# What is required to implement an ADT in Clojure?

Tags: haskell, clojure, adt

Assumption: I'm aware of the [ADT](https://github.com/phansen/com.phansen.clojure.adt) libraries [here](https://gist.github.com/aboekhoff/656004). They're cool. Maybe they could be better.

There is a really interesting example of ADT's in Clojure [here](http://gizmo385.github.io/clojure/programming/2015/08/11/adts-in-clojure.html):

We define an ADT generator like this:

```clj
(defmacro data
  [adt-name equals-sign & constructors]
  `(do
     (defn ~(symbol (str adt-name "?")) [~'obj]
       (= ~(str adt-name) (adt-name ~'obj)))
     ~@(for [[type-name & fields]
             (filter (partial not= '(|))
                     (partition-by (partial = '|) constructors))]
         (apply (partial emit-constructor adt-name type-name)
                 fields))))
```

Given the Haskell example:

```
data Tree a = Empty
        | Leaf a
        | Node Tree Tree
```

Then we write the Clojure

```
(data Tree = Empty | Leaf value | Node left right)
```

Which is pretty cool.

Now I feel like there is something missing from matching up to the Haskell equivalent, but I can't quite put my finger on what it is.

My question is: **What is required to implement an ADT in Clojure?**

Comment: isn't a ADT without a checked types more or less useless? I guess you could represent the ADT as it's catamorphism ... (btw: the pattern-matching / catamorphism to use values is what I would consider missing - of course I don't understand Clojure at all so maybe it's *emited* somehow too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To implement ADT in clojure you're required to be brave and insistent.

For the missing parts - I don't know what are you missing, but I know what I am missing usually.

1) I want to authomatically get some `foldX`-function to perform conversion to Boehm encoding - a natural fold for this datatype.

This, however, will require you to have user to specify which fields must refer to object of same type (`left` and `right` in your case).

For instance, that function, written for your example type in haskell (God save the laziness!) will look like:

```
foldTree :: a -> (v -> a) -> (a -> a -> a) -> Tree v -> a
foldTree empty value node = go 
  where
    go tree =
      case tree of
        Empty    -> empty
        Value v  -> value v
        Node l r -> node (go l) (go r)
```

This is done in Coq, as I know, and called "induction".

2) I want to see predicates like `isEmpty` for all the branches. Seriously. The only language providing them is Pyret.

3) For bonus points, I also want to have some ability to `derive` structural `Eq`uality, `Ord`ering, to- and from-string conversion.

∞-1) To own my soul, you can also automatically generate lenses and prisms into all fields and branches accordingly.

∞) To prove your own strength, you can also generate ana-, para- and apomorphisms, since `foldX` is a already a catamorphism.